# Create a React app for offline development

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a React app that I can use for offline development, without using `create-react-app`

I started by installing Node.js then in VScode terminal
`npm install live-server react react-dom`

My index.html is

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>   
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js is

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const navbar = (
    <h1>Test</h1>
)

ReactDOM.render(navbar, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I am not getting any output when running `live-server`

What am I missing?

Do I need to add these web elements to html header?

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/udm/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>` or `<script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>`

Comment: I tried both, but page shows up as blank